# How to await a Task<T>(async () => ... )

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to execute 4 asynchronous tasks like

```
---- Task 1 -------------------
---- Task 2 -------------------
---- Task 3 ----- Task 4 ------
```

(x-axis is time)

I have

```
Task<T1> doT1 = ...
Task<T2> doT2 = ...
```

and I need a wrapper task `doT3T4` that executes 3 and 4 in sequence, like

```
T3 t3result = await ...
return await SomethingThatUsesT3ResultAsync(t3result);
```

so I can then do

```
await Task.WhenAll(doT1, doT2, doT3T4);
```

I tried

```
var doT3T4 = new Task<T4>(async () => {
  T3 t3result = await ...
  return await SomethingThatUsesT3ResultAsync(t3result);
});
```

but that gives me the error

> Cannot convert async lambda expression to ...

Comment: Is what you want not .ContinueWith()

Comment: Why do you need a wrapper task? `T3 t3result = await ...; var doT3T4 = SomethingUsesT3ResultAsync(t3result); await Task.WhenAll(doT1, doT2, doT3T4);` would have the same semantics.

Comment: as @pm_2 mentioned take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=netframework-4.7#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_ContinueWith_System_Action_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__

Comment: Where have you seen that directly instantiating a `Task` is a good practice or that it should even be done?

Answer (score 0):

Put tasks 3 and 4 in the method

```
public async Task RunTask3And4()
{
    var result3 = await RunTask3();
    await RunTask4(result3);
}
```

Then use with other tasks

```
var tasks = new[]
{
    RunTask1(),
    RunTask2(),
    RunTask3And4()
};
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```