# How to get await an array οf tasks (Task<T>[]) to become an array of things (T[])?

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, task-parallel-library

*This is not a question on how to use `async` and `await` in general. It considers a very specific case that I haven't found in the documentation.*

I have a setup of types that I'm not used to. Usually, I put the `await` and the `Task<Whatever>` gets de-task'ified to the type it's going to have in the end. Now and I got stuck on the following and after a while of trying, I realize I don't know how to get rid of the `Task<Thing>` type in the `output`. I want it to be `Thing` only.

```
Task<Thing>[] output = list.Select(async a => new Thing
{
    Id = a.Id,
    Name = a.Name,
    Props = (await SomeService.GetAsync(a))
      .Select(b => b.Value).ToArray()
}).ToArray();
```

The requirement is that the declaration of `output` is explicit (i.e. no `var`) and that it's not asynchronous (i.e. no `Task`). The type of `output` must be `Thing[]` and I prefer not to use `Task.WhenAll(output)` as it requires declaring `output` earlier, which breaks the first two requirements.

The inner `await` is required in order to be able to apply `Select`. But that imposes the outer `async`, hence making it an array of tasks of things (i.e. `Task<Thing>`[]), instead of an array of things (i.e. `Thing[]`).

I can't put `await` in front of the list because an array of tasks isn't awaitable. I can't put it inside the lamba expression becuase it breaks the syntax.

I've made a few searches for syntaxes and examples but this is a bit uncommon scenario so I found little of value. Can even be done? I'm convinced it can but I can't figure our how. I have found only [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50091440/1525840). It's related but not sufficiently similar, though. And the answer doesn't actually show how to achieve what I want (which is eliminating `var` and `Task` in the variable declaration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're looking for [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall):

```cs
Thing[] result = await Task.WhenAll(output);
```

To avoid having to use `Task<Thing>[]` anywhere, or putting a long expression as an argument for `Task.WhenAll`, you could write an extension method:

```cs
public static class TaskEnumerable
{
    public static Task<T[]> WhenAllTasks<T>(this IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks) =>
        Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Your code can then be:

```cs
Thing[] output = await list.Select(async a => new Thing
{
    Id = a.Id,
    Name = a.Name,
    Props = (await SomeService.GetAsync(a))
      .Select(b => b.Value).ToArray()
}).WhenAllTasks();
```

Comment: Sort of. That option requires that `output` is declared and the type of that declaration is the object of my reluctance for `var` (full metal jacket OCD). And I'm not allowed by the team to use "long" types (due to their full metal jacket OCD against `Dictionary<Dictionary<KeyValuePair>,...>`). Are you saying that this is the only way (other than not declaring `output` and instead copying the full expression into the `WhenAll` method)? In that case, I prefer `var`...   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten: I don't really understand what you're asking. Your question doesn't use any anonymous types, which is typically where `var` is required - I've answered what you asked (awaiting a `Task<Thing>[]` to get a `Thing[]`). You only mention `var` in the very last sentence, in parentheses, not having used `var` anywhere in your code sample. As far as I can see, I answered the question you actually asked - if you were trying to ask something different, please clarify in the question.

Comment: Apologies for being unclear. In my example, I have `Task<Thing>[]`, which is frowned upon by the team as they dislike it and prefer using there `var` instead, which I dislike. They would be fine with `Thing[]`, though, so I'm trying to figure out a way to make everybody happy.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: I suggest you make that *much* clearer in the question then. I think I can solve that with an extension method.

Comment: Updated the question to make it **abundantly** much clearer now.